# Number of cubes which a line passes through

Tags: geometry, contest-math

A $100×100×100$ cube $PQRSTUVW$ is made of $1×1×1$ non-overlapping cubes. $Z$ is a point on PS such that $PZ = 33$. Through how many of these $1×1×1$ cubes does $VZ$ pass? (AMC 2015, Senior)

[image: diagram]

Not really sure how to approach this one, think that there may be something to do with a $3$D plane and vectors, but again still a bit lost. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the view of a simplified version of the problem ($10 \times 10 \times 10$), in which only cubes in the first four layers are shown as we needn't consider cubes beyond the fourth layer.  (Stack Exchange will not allow the uploading of large image files, so I cannot show the full $100 \times 100 \times 100$ case, but this will suffice to illustrate the issues.  I'll perform the full calculation, below, however.)

The purple dots show where the line in the problem transitions from one layer to the next.

[image]

Here's just the first layer:

[image]

Here's just the second layer:

[image]

Here's just the third layer:

[image]

Here is just the fourth layer:[image]

We want to know when the line passes from one layer of cubes to the next. 
 If we use the natural coordinates, the equation of the line in the full problem, as viewed perpendicular to the $QRSB$ plane, is:

$z = 100 - {100 \over 33} x$.

We set $x = 1, 2, \ldots, 33$ to find the heights ($z$ values) where the line passes from one plane of cubes to the next.  The heights are:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & z \\  
 1. & 96.9697 \\
 2. & 93.9394 \\
 3. & 90.9091 \\
 4. & 87.8788 \\
 5. & 84.8485 \\
 6. & 81.8182 \\
 7. & 78.7879 \\
 8. & 75.7576 \\
 9. & 72.7273 \\
 10. & 69.697 \\
 11. & 66.6667 \\
 12. & 63.6364 \\
 13. & 60.6061 \\
 14. & 57.5758 \\
 15. & 54.5455 \\
 16. & 51.5152 \\
 17. & 48.4848 \\
 18. & 45.4545 \\
 19. & 42.4242 \\
 20. & 39.3939 \\
 21. & 36.3636 \\
 22. & 33.3333 \\
 23. & 30.303 \\
 24. & 27.2727 \\
 25. & 24.2424 \\
 26. & 21.2121 \\
 27. & 18.1818 \\
 28. & 15.1515 \\
 29. & 12.1212 \\
 30. & 9.09091 \\
 31. & 6.06061 \\
 32. & 3.0303 \\
 33. & 0. \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

Thus we can count the number of cubes traversed by the line in the first layer of cubes by considering only the heights ($z$ values) from $100$ to $96.9$.  Likewise, for cubes traversed in the second layer between $96.9$ and $93.94$.  And so on.  The cells are on the diagonal (as viewed from a point perpendicular to the $PQVW$ plane).

The number of cells traversed in each layer is $\lceil z(i) \rceil - \lfloor z(i+1) \rfloor$, where $z(i)$ is the height at the (back) boundary to layer $i$.  There are four such cubes in each layer.  Thus the total number of cells is $4 \times 32 = 132$, just as Ross Millikan showed.

Answer (score 1):

If the line were $VP$ it would pass along the face diagonals of $100$ cubes.  On its way it crosses $32$ plane boundaries in the $VS$ direction, which adds $32$ more cubes for a total of $132$

Comment: Doesn't seem right to me because when the line is off the $PQVW$ face by more than 1.0, it no longer passes through some of the 100 original cubes you mentioned.  Moreover, by your logic a line from $V$ to $S$ should pass through 200 cubes, but instead it passes through only 100 (i.e., those on the diagonal).  Right?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: as you move the line off the original face, you miss some in that layer but make it up in the next layers.  It is important that when you do the diagonal (face or body) you pass through vertices so don't pass through the cube on either side.  You can draw a $4 \times 6$ rectangle and count the main diagonal, then a line that goes from lower left to a little below the upper right.  The second will go through $9$ squares because it misses all the vertices.  The first goes through one vertex and only passes through eight squares.